# Using IRT, how would you find the updated ability of someone after answering a calibrated item?

Tags: item-response-theory

For this project, I have a list of items that were calibrated under the 3PL model using the mirt package. I had a pilot study run to help estimate these items. Now, using a different group of people, I want to figure out how to update someone's ability (assuming it's zero) when they answer a calibrated item (right or wrong). Is there a method of doing this in mirt or any other package in R.

Underneath is somewhat what I want but this is for a 1PL model. If anyone can guide me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]